# Meaning of "money leaving the space for lower-hanging fruit." in the context of economics

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

To be more precise, I copied the whole sentence here. Can you understand the following sentence? if u do, could u please explain what "money leaving the space" means in it.

> That's really the driver that seems to be the culprit in money leaving
> the space for lower-hanging fruit.

The article from which this sentence was taken out is about economics, and the word driver apparently refers to "a factor that has a material effect on the activity of another entity." ([Driver definition in economics](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/driver.asp))

Thanks for your time

Comment: "money" here is a euphemism for investors; "the space" refers to the specific market or area of investment; "lower-hanging fruit" refers to more likely investment opportunities. (The only source I'm citing here is my own literary and business experience. Call it opinion if you like, but I'm right.)

Comment: I agree with RobJarvis; to put it another way, whatever "that" is, it's the reason investors are choosing to spend their money on easier opportunities in other areas.

Comment: RobJarvis and Hellion seem to be correct. Please notice "That's really the driver that seems to be the culprit in money leaving the space for lower-hanging fruit…" isn't a great example of economics, English or anything else.

First, "… the driver that seems to be the culprit…" is clear tautology; saying the same thing twice.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yeah. Exactly. The sentence is unnecessarily convoluted. It certainly could be written simpler, so all readers—even those not familiar with economics— could have a high chance of understanding it. I mean using metaphors or idioms is not bad, but it wouldn't hurt to say things directly when it comes to complex and important stuff.

Comment: Sorry, Guys. Ignoring the driver/culprit tautology would have left space to explain low-hanging fruit occupies the easy space.

@navid.h True, and not far enough. Worse than "unnecessarily convoluted", 'That's really the driver that seems to be the culprit in money leaving the space for lower-hanging fruit' is  pretentious, not meaningful.

Sadly, "The article from which this sentence was taken out" reveals the commentator's lack of familiarity with English, amplified by defining 'driver' as apparently referring to "a factor that has a material effect on the activity of another entity."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The money is [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) for the investors, and [low-hanging fruit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/low-hanging%20fruit) is an idiom for

> the obvious or easy things that can be most readily done or dealt with
> in achieving success or making progress toward an objective

"leaving the space" is not an idiom but an intelligible metaphor saying that investors are leaving this area of investment for others where profits are more easily made.